# How can I remotely manage files on a usb drive attached to an Android TV

Tags: file-transfer, android-tv

I would like to

- send files to a usb hard drive attached to my Android TV
- from my (Windows) PC

How can I do that?

---

Both the Android TV and my PC are connected to the same Wifi Network

Answer (score 0):

Install teamViewer app on your TV and PC.
Then you can connect using it from your PC as remote.

But teamviewer consumes data for this. So, if you have an unlimited data plan try this.